# Replacing a string with object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, substring

I have a string

```
var str="{name:'qwer',age:24,gender:'male'}"
```

and I have an object with same property

```
var object = {name : zxcvb}
```

By matching the property (`name`) of the object, I want to overwrite the property value inside the string with the value from the object. The desired output is:

```
newString = "{name:'zxcvb',age:24,gender:'male'}"
```

Please let me know if you need any clarifications. Can we achieve this by regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the object, building a RegExp out of the `key` and substituting the `value` on a match:

```js
let str = "{name:'qwer',age:24,gender:'male',aname:'xyz',namey:'pqr'}";
const obj = {
  name: 'zxcvb'
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${key}\\s*:\\s*'[^']+'`);
  str = str.replace(regex, `${key}:'${value}'`);
}
console.log(str);
```